# Strange riddle with easy answer

Tags: riddle

I have no clue who wrote this riddle (I did change it a bit) but the person was a teacher. A student did manage to answer it despite the adults' heads scratching. The riddle is as follows:

> I am the start of eternity,
>
> And the beginning to an end.
>
> I wait at the start of an envelope,
>
> And watch you thrice from enlightenment.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: @Stevo I will add the attributions in, thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> the letter "e"

Which

> Starts eternity
>  Begins end
>  Starts envelope
>  And appears 3 times in enlightenment.